# Problem with blur effect in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am following Andrew Price's Earth tutorial for the lens flare and I set up my sun object just as he did, gave a pass index, etc. and rendered. Around 42:00, he adds a Fast Gaussian blur node with a ColorRamp to intensify the blur. This all worked fine.

Then, he mixes the add node and the alpha over node. Then, he increases the Add factor amount and the size of the sun object changes.

When I do this, only the glow increases.

I apologize if this is trivial, but I need this for a good lens flare.
In short, the size of the sun is not increasing and hence the blur effect isn't working well.

[The Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q8PwcDzb8Y)

Before changing the factor:
[image: Before changing the factor]

[image: After changing the factor]

Blend file:
[image]